# PHP - Strange for loop results

Tags: php, mysql

**I am doing a forum based on home works.** I have a php code that retrieves data from the database but it shows wrong resuts. **Say there are 3 users = *A*, *B*, *C* and say user *A* enters "hello", it shows that all users *A*, *B* and *C* entered "hello."**

***The PHP CODE*:**

```
<?php 
    require 'database2.php';
    $myquery="SELECT * FROM `accounts`,`data`";
    $query = mysql_query($myquery);

 if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

    $data = array();

 for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo "<tr>";    

    echo "<td>".$data[$x]["school"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["standard"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["subject"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["chapter"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["type"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["description"]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$data[$x]["username"]."</td>";
}
#header('Content-Type: application/json');
#echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);
?>
```

**The Result is:**

[Not expected as result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KxPf.png)

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. They are also insecure. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: u need data from two tables? ``accounts`,`data``

Comment: Use joins if you need to fetch relational data...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Yes I need data from two tables

Comment: what is the relation bw ``accounts`,`data``  ?? can u use join here?

Comment: There is no relation

Comment: in `$data` which value belongs to accounts and which belongs to data?

Comment: I didnt specify that

Comment: Please share your table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **@devpro** and **@Magnus Eriksson** . The mistake was ***didn't join according to username***.

***The small PHP Change is:***

```
$myquery="SELECT * FROM `accounts`,`data` where user=username";
```

*All that was needed is to add where*